# Hosts file working partially on Fedora

Tags: linux, .htaccess, dns, host, hosts

I am having the following `/etc/hosts` file :

```
    127.0.0.1          localhost.localdomain localhost
::1                    localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
192.168.10.139/azc     clientdomain.com www.clientdomain.com
80.230.215.84          home_server
```

The first, second and fourth line are working normally. However the third isn't. I tried to look for "invisible characters" and rewrote the whole line without copy-pasting anything, but the `clientdomain.com` query in my browser or via ping still brings me to my client's IP address.

Am I not allowed to use paths at all in my hosts file, just sheer IP addresses?
If I take out the `/azc` bit, the redirection does happens correctly.

I don't manage to have it working through .htaccess redirections either...

Comment: Name resolution using DNS is a completely different protocol than HTTP, so you cannot put paths in the hosts file because it doesn't mean anything.  Perhaps you could say more about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to access the code of the site I am building entering my client's domain name within the browser's address bar. The code resides at `/var/www/html/azc`

Answer (score 0):

I was actually trying to redirect a domain name to a specific folder on my server.
I finally discovered (Doh!!) that Apache has a dedicated feature for this called `VirtualHost`.

[This post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-6) explains very well how to set one.

I hope this helps.